How am I supposed to check the validity of a UTF8 string without buffer overflow?
When looking for a UTF8 handling library for C I found this, which seems to be the most popular on GitHub. It overruns the buffer you pass it to the UTF8 validation function:
#include "utf8.h"
int main()
{
    unsigned char c[] = { 0b11110000, 0b10000000, 0 };
    

    utf8_int8_t* is_valid = utf8valid((char*)c);

}

The part of the code that overruns the buffer is:
if (0xf0 == (0xf8 & *str)) {
    /* ensure that there's 4 bytes or more remaining */
    if (remaining < 4) {
        return (utf8_int8_t*)str;
    }
    
    /* ensure each of the 3 following bytes in this 4-byte
     * utf8 codepoint began with 0b10xxxxxx */
    if ((0x80 != (0xc0 & str[1])) || (0x80 != (0xc0 & str[2])) ||
        (0x80 != (0xc0 & str[3]))) {
        return (utf8_int8_t*)str;
    }

When it reads at str[3] it reads past the buffer I allocated, even though my string buffer was null terminated. Is this behaviour normal for a validation UTF8 function or expected? There is a utf8nvalid() function where you pass a max buffer size, but in the function it explicitly checks the null-terminator so it seems to think that it's protecting against buffer overflows. I think it's broken. The code is a single header, it's here

That code you show, where do you get that? I can find parts of the code you show, but not auto val = str[3];. And the auto part makes it look like C++, not C (unless you're using C23 which changes the meaning of the auto keyword).

As for the problem, perhaps you should be using utf8nvalid instead, where you can pass in the correct length of the string.

And if you give invalid input, then you will get invalid results (or UB like in your case). On the other hand, having a function to check if the input is valid, which doesn't take into account that actual invalid input may be passed, might be considered a bug. YMMV.

@Someprogrammerdude Sorry, that was my addition when I was debugging, it's a relatively small library, 2000 lines, it's in the  utf8nvalid() function. This seems really bad, it seems to branch three times before it gets to a 0 - 127 case, which probably are the most common, as it first tests 4-byte, 3-byte, 2-byte, and then 1-byte. I think I'm going to try to write my own.

When fed with your string, this code does not read str[3] because || short-circuits at (0x80 != (0xc0 & str[2])), which evaluates to 1.
Neither valgrind nor libasan see anything wrong with this code either.

Strange, Visual Studio sanitizer throws an error. Is short circuiting behaviour not meant to happen in debug builds or something?

@Zebrafish not sure about Visual Studio, perhaps it's their bug.

I'm guessing you looked through the code yourself, do you think it's a bad idea to start the conditional statement with 4 byte check instead of 1 byte, as ASCII is probably more likely, right?

I agree that starting with 4-byte check is probably suboptimal. but it should be easy to modify. You can send a PR...

Presumably remaining < 4 would be true in this case, so the code shouldn't even get to the short-circuiting if statement to begin with. But in this situation that is not the case, because utf8valid() calls utf8nvalid() with SIZE_MAX as the buffer size, which allows utf8nvalid() to go out of bounds as remaining would be a very large number. Looks like utf8len() has a similar problem, too.  Looking at the repo's Issues list, there are a few tickets related to reading out of bounds. So I would suggest finding a less buggy library.

@RemyLebeau Please show where exactly utf8nvalid goes out of bounds. My incomplete checks do not show any such thing, neither do tools that designed to find out of bounds accesses, but perhaps you have more data than I do. The issue I see in the repo is bogus. The supposedly bad code is exactly the same as here. It will go out of bounds if your array is not null-terminated, but then every single string function will do the same, so unless you also complain that strlen and printf are inherently buggy, this is a non-issue.
